# Input from text file to array

Tags: java

The input will be a text file with an arbitrary amount of integers from 0-9 with NO spaces. How do I populate an array with these integers so I can sort them later?

What I have so far is as follows:

```
BufferedReader numInput = null;
    int[] theList;
    try {
        numInput = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    int i = 0;
    while(numInput.ready()){
        theList[i] = numInput.read();
        i++;
```

Obviously theList isn't initialized, but I don't know what the length will be. Also I'm not too sure about how to do this in general. Thanks for any help I receive.

To clarify the input, it will look like:
    1236654987432165498732165498756484654651321
I won't know the length, and I only want the single integer characters, not multiple. So 0-9, not 0-10 like I accidentally said earlier.

Comment: My bad--meant to say 0-9, not -10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going for Collection API i.e. ArrayList

```
ArrayList a=new Arraylist();
while(numInput.ready()){
       a.add(numInput.read());
}
```

Comment: This is only part of the problem.  There's also the issue of the return value of `BufferedReader.read()`.

Comment: So now I'm populating an array list. All is good in that department, but I'm read input as integers of two characters long. i.e. i'm getting    numInput.get(0) to return 49 when it should equal 4

Comment: You probably have to subtract '0' from the value returned by read. Like `a.add(numInput.read() - '0');`

Comment: Thanks David! That worked and I don't know why; I wouldn't mind an explanation if you're up for one.

Comment: It's a problem of ASCII encoding. Text in a text file is stored as numeric values and the character '0' is not stored with value 0. It is stored with value 48. '0' is a way to say "the ASCII value for character 0" (sort of).

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking that after I asked for an explanation. I guess I should have assumed it was returning ASCII when Java Docs said read returned an integer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `List<Integer>` instead of a `int[]`. Using a `List<Integer>`, you can add items as desired, the `List` will grow along. If you are done, you can use the [`toArray(int[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28T%5b%5d%29) method to transform the `List` into an `int[]`.

Answer (score 0):

1 . Use guava to nicely read file's 1st line into 1 `String`

[readFirstLine](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Files.html#readFirstLine%28java.io.File,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29)

2 . convert that String [to char array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29) - because all of your numbers are one digit lengh, so they are in fact `char`s

3 . convert chars to integers.

4 . add them to list.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String s = "1236654987432165498732165498756484654651321";
    char[] charArray = s.toCharArray();
    List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>(charArray.length);
    for (char c : charArray) {
        Integer integer = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(c));
        numbers.add(integer);
    }

    System.out.println(numbers);
}
```

prints: `[1, 2, 3, 6, 6, 5, 4, 9, 8, 7, 4, 3, 2, 1, 6, 5, 4, 9, 8, 7, 3, 2, 1, 6, 5, 4, 9, 8, 7, 5, 6, 4, 8, 4, 6, 5, 4, 6, 5, 1, 3, 2, 1]`